# How to choose word for pumping lemma for $a^kb^{2k}a^k$?

Tags: regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I have to show that the language $ \mathcal {L} = \{a ^ k b ^ {2k} a ^ k: k \geq 0 \} $ is not a regular language. So that's what I want to use the pumping motto for. What I could do is this: let $ \ sigma = a^Nb^{2N}a^N $, where $| \sigma | = 4N \geq N $, fulfilling that $ \alpha \beta^k \gamma$. But at the moment of being able to separate $ \alpha \beta $ I am very complicated and I cannot reach the possible cases.

Comment: Please do not delete your question after receiving an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful not only to you but also to others in the future.  Deleting your question after receiving an answer can be considered impolite to answerers.

Comment: Do not edit your post to ask another question.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|\alpha \beta|\leq N$, then $\beta = a^i$, $i>0$. You can take it from here.